# Calling methods side by side in a table

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm making a table with Decimal, Binary, Octal and Hexadecimal columns. I wrote methods that display each of these types from a low number to a high number. My question is **how do I display these methods side by side** so they line up in the appropriate column?

I tried using the following, but it contains "invalid arguments":

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t...", generate.buildDecimal(), generate.buildBinary(),...)
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;

public class Converter
{
    int decimal0;
    int decimal1;
    int decimal2;
    int decimal3;
    int bottomLimit;
    int topLimit;

    // prompt user for range of numbers to display
    public void PromptUser()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter bottom limit: ");
        bottomLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        decimal0 = bottomLimit;
        decimal1 = bottomLimit;
        decimal2 = bottomLimit;
        decimal3 = bottomLimit;

        Console.Write("Enter top limit: ");
        topLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    // display decimal values in range
    public void buildDecimal()
    {
        while (decimal0 <= topLimit)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(decimal0);
            decimal0++;
        }
    }

    // display binary values in range
    public void buildBinary()
    {
        while (decimal1 <= topLimit)
        {
            string binary = Convert.ToString(decimal1, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(binary);
            decimal1++;
        }
    }

    // display octal values in range
    public void buildOctal()
    {
        while (decimal2 <= topLimit)
        {
            string octal = Convert.ToString(decimal2, 8);
            Console.WriteLine(octal);
            decimal2++;
        }
    }

    // display hexadecimal values in range
    public void buildHex()
    {
        while (decimal3 <= topLimit)
        {
            string hex = Convert.ToString(decimal3, 16);
            Console.WriteLine(hex);
            decimal3++;
        }
    }

    // call methods
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Converter generate = new Converter();

        generate.PromptUser();

        Console.WriteLine("Decimal    Binary     Octal      Hexadecimal");

        generate.buildDecimal();
        generate.buildBinary();
        generate.buildOctal();
        generate.buildHex();

    }
}
```

As of right now, the program returns something like this:

```
Enter bottom limit: 1
Enter top limit: 10
Decimal    Binary     Octal      Hexadecimal
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
1000
1001
1010
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
10
11
12
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
a
```

If you can't tell from my code, I'm a beginner, so please try not to go too far over my head. I'm actually supposed to put all of the methods in a separate class, but I couldn't figure out how to call the methods. I tried to call them in Converter with *something like*:

```
    Converter callMethod = new Converter();
    callMethod.buildDecimal();
```

But it didn't know what I was referring to.

Comment: FYI, you don't have to prefix your questions with "C#:". That's what we use tags for on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the bottom limit/top limit are always the same you could just use a single method.
see below.

```
   public void BuildNumbers()
    {

        while (decimal1 <= topLimit)
        {
            string binary = Convert.ToString(decimal1, 2);
            string dec = Convert.ToString(decimal1);
            string oct = Convert.ToString(decimal1, 8);
            string hex = Convert.ToString(decimal1, 16);
            Console.Write(binary);
            Console.Write('\t');
            Console.Write(dec);
            Console.Write('\t');
            Console.Write(oct);
            Console.Write('\t');
            Console.Write(hex);
            Console.WriteLine();
            decimal1++;
        }
    }
```